# Different Json based on the type of the variable

Tags: json, scala, spray

I have:

```
case class A(a: T, b: String)
```

and I want different json based on the different type of the variable a of the class A.

For example I want json like `{ "aaa": "value", "b":"value"}` if type is T1 
and I want json like `{ "bbb": "value", "b":"value"}` if type is T2.

I am using spray json

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide a custom protocol:

```
implicit object AJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[A] {
    def write(foo: A) = JsObject(
      foo.a match {
        case a: T1 => "aaa" -> JString(a)
        case a: T2 => "bbb" -> Jstring(a)
      },
      "b" -> JString(foo.b))
}
```